# Any way to increase border gesture width?

Tags: settings, quick-settings

I have a case for my tablet that covers just 1-2mm of the edge of the screen. I love the case, but it makes accessing the notifications pull-down menu very difficult.

Is there anyway to increase the pull-down range height so that I can access it more easily with the case on?

Comment: On older device you may be able to reduce the screen height a few pixels so that the used screen size better matches the actual border by the case. There are a few questions and answers here on Stackexchange that describe how to do so, usually because the screen is partially broken and touch does no longer work in a certain screen area.